# How can I destroy my infra when pipeline fails on 'build' stage?

Tags: deployment, terraform, gitlab-ci, pipeline

My base .gitlab-ci.yml code is the following

```
include:
 - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
 - init
 - validate
 - build
 - deploy
 - cleanup
init:
 extends: .terraform:fmt
validate:
 extends: .terraform:validate
build:
 extends: .terraform:build
deploy:
 extends: .terraform:deploy
 dependencies:
   - build
 allow_failure: true
cleanup:
 extends: .terraform:destroy
 dependencies:
   - build
```

The build stage failed but did create some resources in AWS. Then, cleanup successes with the following:

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
No changes. No objects need to be destroyed.
Either you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were
already deleted outside of Terraform.

Please keep it simple, I'm a newborn baby into this

Comment: Failed in what way? The behavior described indicates that the resources created were never written to the state file, so terraform has no real way to know they exist unless you `import` them into state.

Comment: @jordanm The build stage was not successful because I had already created some of the resources in the cloud, so the infra code found duplicates How can I manage to perform you suggestion about importing into state?

Comment: This usually occurs because the state is not preserved between pipeline stages.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting to do that, especially as not part of a pipeline. I believe @MattSchuchard is correct that the issue is that you're writing to a local state file and not preserving it through your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know exactly which terraform commands your pipeline jobs are running.

Generally though, you should be able to comment out the TF code for your resource(s) and run the pipeline again to delete them.